# Aggregate Function not available as Article in Merge Rep Publication

Tags: sql-server, winforms, replication, aggregate-functions

I have Merge Replication set up and I just noticed that a Aggregate Function is not available on my Subscriber.  After further investigation I discovered that is is not even available in the Publication as an option.  There are other Functions listed there but not that one.

Ideas?

Is there something written that doesn't allow Aggregate's to be in a Replication Scheme?  If so how would I go about getting this to my local DB's?

Below is a CREATE TO of the Aggregate Function.  Thanks!

```
USE [Connect]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedAggregate [dbo].[CommaDelimitedString]    Script Date: 06/03/2009 16:21:07 ******/
CREATE AGGREGATE [dbo].[CommaDelimitedString]
(@value [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS[nvarchar](4000)
EXTERNAL NAME [SqlServerProject1].[SqlServerProject1.CommaDelimitedString]
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'AutoDeployed', @value=N'yes' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'AGGREGATE',@level1name=N'CommaDelimitedString'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'SqlAssemblyFile', @value=N'CommaDelimitedString.vb' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'AGGREGATE',@level1name=N'CommaDelimitedString'
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'SqlAssemblyFileLine', @value=12 , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'AGGREGATE',@level1name=N'CommaDelimitedString'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like a CLR user defined aggregate. To my knowledge those cannot be transfered using replication, but must be installed beforehand in each participating database.